# Need to list all the sites under a google domain using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to list all the sites under a google domain using Google Apps Script. I have written a small script, but it only returns the sites I have created:

```js
function list_sites() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('SiteList1');
  var domain = 'test.com';
  var sites = SitesApp.getSites(domain);

  doc.appendParagraph("Top");
  doc.appendParagraph(sites);
  doc.appendParagraph("Bottom");

  doc.saveAndClose(); // Save and close the document
}
```

How do I get all the sites?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the getAllSites method.

```
SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, start, max)
```

I'm not sure why it's seemingly undocumented and not in the API doc but [you can find references to it](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sitesapp.getallsites%22) and I have production scripts that use it daily.

Comment: Thanks for the help, SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, start, max) seems to get all of the sites into an array of sites, if I do   var sites = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, start, max) and the print out just 'sites' I get the word sites and many times as there are entries in the array,  how can I print each site name from the array

Comment: Each item in your "sites" variable will be a site object. The Site class is documented here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_site. You can therefore you can do site.getName() to return the name of each site.

Don't forget to "accept" this answer (over on the left) if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

The example Peter mentioned, did not work for me, see also this question: [Why does SitesApp.getSites(myDomain) not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500256/why-does-sitesapp-getsitesmydomain-not-work) 
But I found a solution which also might help you:

```
function list_sites() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('SiteList1');
  var domain = 'example.com';
  var site = SitesApp.getSite(domain);

  doc.appendParagraph("Top");
  var pages = site.getAllDescendants();
  for (i in pages) {
    doc.appendParagraph(pages[i].getTitle());
  }  

  doc.appendParagraph("Bottom");
  doc.saveAndClose(); // Save and close the document  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/eduvik/46bb72f3ffea57402b3f

Needs to be run as an admin user

```
function listSites() {
  var domain = UserManager.getDomain();
  var PAGE_LENGTH=200;
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sites = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain,0,PAGE_LENGTH);
  for(var i=0; sites.length != 0; i+=PAGE_LENGTH){
    for (var j=0; j<sites.length; j++) {
      sheet.appendRow([sites[j].getUrl()]);
    }
    sites = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, i, PAGE_LENGTH);
  }
};
```