# Why does SitesApp.getSites(myDomain) not work?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently playing around with Google Apps Script and can't get the following snippet to work. 
[image]

The error message is: **the requested resource was not found.**
[image]
I also tested the undocumented method which I found here: [Need to list all the sites under a google domain using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395695/need-to-list-all-the-sites-under-a-google-domain-using-google-apps-script)

```
    var mySites = SitesApp.getAllSites(myDomain, 1, 10);
```

but I get the same error. For the complete example, see below. Thank you in advance.

```
function view() {
  var myDomain = 'example.com';

  // this works
  var mySite = SitesApp.getSite(myDomain);
  Logger.log('title=' + mySite.getTitle() + '\n' + 'name=' + mySite.getName());

  // this works, too
  var myPages = mySite.getAllDescendants();
  for (i in myPages) {
    Logger.log('page=' + myPages[i].getTitle());
  }  

  //this does not work, error: the requested ressource was not found
  var mySites = SitesApp.getSites(myDomain);

  // this also does not work, same error
  var mySites = SitesApp.getAllSites(myDomain, 1, 10);
}
```

**EDIT 1**: I tested with 3 different browsers on Windows 7: Firefox Nightly, Google Chrome and Opera.
**EDIT 2**: Same error on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1N with Android 3.2 and Firefox browser.

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't work. Just to make sure, are you sure that the script is running as a user under example.com

Comment: yes, the script is running as a user under example.com, as you can see, the other 2 examples are working...

Comment: any reason for the downvote now more than > 2.5 years later?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get that error when the service can't find the domain or you don't have access to it. Please ensure that the domain matches exactly, and doesn't start with "www.", etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, as already mentioned, the script is running as a user under example.com and as you can see, the other 2 examples are working...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
  var mySite = 'https://sites.google.com/site/name_of_the_site';
  var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(mySite);
```

Comment: Thank you! It has been a while since I asked that... I will see, when I will test your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below line

```
for(i=0;i<=80;i++) { 

Logger.log('title=' + mySite[i].getTitle() + '\n' + 'name=' + mySite[i].getName());

 }
```