# Google Docs Sheets onChange() - determine which sheet was changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am working with a Google Docs sheet that many people will have access to edit.  I need to be able to tell when sheets are changed, i.e. added or removed rows or columns.  I am able to get an onChange event when this occurs, but I can't seem to find which sheet was changed.  The event contains a reference to the [SpreadSheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) but `getActiveSheet` always returns the first sheet regardless of which sheet was active.

I created a new spreadsheet with 3 sheets, added the following script and authorized it.

```
function onOpen() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onChange")
   .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
   .onChange()
   .create();
}
function onChange(e) {
  Logger.log(e)
  Logger.log("Name: " + e.source.getName())
  Logger.log("Active Sheet: " + e.source.getActiveSheet().getName())
  Logger.log("All Sheets: " + e.source.getSheets().map(function(s){return s.getName()}))
}
```

The I went to Sheet 2 and deleted a column.  The log showed:

```
[14-07-17 19:13:32:774 EDT] {changeType=REMOVE_COLUMN, source=Spreadsheet, authMode=FULL}
[14-07-17 19:13:32:861 EDT] Name: Untitled spreadsheet
[14-07-17 19:13:32:944 EDT] Active Sheet: Sheet1
[14-07-17 19:13:32:946 EDT] All Sheets: Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3
```

So event though I had Sheet 2 active and the operation affected only sheet 2, the event passed to the onChange handler seems to indicate that Sheet 1 was active at the time.

How can I find out which sheet was really changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the change event [isn't supposed to return 'source'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) even though it does in the logs.

I'm having the same behaviour as you. I am able to get the sheet name with 'on edit' but that doesn't suit what you're trying to do.

I also tried using a combindation of onedit and onchange triggers, but they won't fire at the same time, only one or the other.

[This is worth submitting on the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: Turns out there are a couple of issues there already: [4033](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4033), [3926](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3926&q=onChange&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner), [3269](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3269&q=onChange&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

Comment: @joe - The issue closest to yours is [Issue 2751](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2751), and it's also the most popular of the open ones, so most likely to get attention. The fact that you're able to retrieve `source` makes me suspect that it's actually being worked on - there have been times in past when undocumented objects showed up ([sometimes shakily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500256)), and then came out as features.

Comment: For anyone finding this in the future, this was fixed in issue [3926](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3926).  `e.source.getActiveSheet()` now returns the correct sheet

Comment: e.source.getActiveSheet() doesn't work as per today!